# How to get a useful backtrace in Cygwin?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, cygwin, backtrace

Although I have compiled my C program with `-g -O0`, the backtrace I get from gdb is useless:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x6113759d in wordfree () from /cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin/cygwin1.dll
#1  0x75141375 in OutputDebugStringA () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll
#2  0x40010006 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Is there any way to get a useful backtrace in Cygwin?

My gdb version is `7.3.50.20111026-cvs (cygwin-special)`, gcc is `4.5.3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"bt full" should give you better results.

Comment: No, it just tells me that there is `No symbol table info available` after each line.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct thread selected. try `info threads` and then `thread <num>`.